# How to change the inner RippleColor and UnboundedRipple effects in Angular material button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

**I have used the following material design button in my project:-**

```
<button class="save-btn" mat-raised-button>Save Changes</button>
```

**I want to change its default ripple color. I tried this:-**

```
<button class="save-btn" mat-raised-button matRipple [matRippleUnbounded]="false" [matRippleColor]="rgba(255,255,0,0.3)">Save Changes</button>
```

My desired color is applied but the ripple effect is unbounded. I cannot bound it.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spswae). Can you please explain bit more about it?

Comment: @PankajParkar I could change the ripple color but when I click it, the ripple effect leaks out of the button. I need bounded ripple.

Comment: @PankajParkar Its a css bug, due to mat-raised-button `<section>
  <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button
      class="save-btn"
      mat-raised-button
      style="overflow: hidden"
      mat-ripple
      [matRippleUnbounded]="false"
      class="my-ripple-container"
      [matRippleColor]="'rgba(255,255,0,0.3)'"
    >
      Save Changes
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
`

Comment: @NarenMurali awesome Naren, please add as an answer. If you;re okay, I prepared an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spswae) for you, feel free to use it

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks. using `style="overflow: hidden"` solved my problem.

Comment: @AlexWright please answer your own question and mark it as closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, it seems to be a bug in angular material. You can simply use `overflow: hidden` as CSS style.